# What is hsrc attribute for a image in Html?

Tags: html

I came across this piece of Html code. I have searched W3School and Google for this but there is no meaningful search result. So my question is `hsrc` a valid Html attribute. Take a look at the following html code.

```
<img src="https://www.taxdisc.direct.gov.uk/EvlPortalApp/framework/images/en/buttons/next.gif" master="true" alt="Next" hsrc="/EvlPortalApp/framework/images/en/buttons/next_rollover.gif">
```

It has an attribute `hsrc="/EvlPortalApp/framework/images/en/buttons/next_rollover.gif"` for an `Img` tag. Anyone has any idea of what this is or is it just a custom attribute?

Comment: @wmfrancia: W3Schools is hardly an authoritative source.  (Consider it the `hsrc` of authority on the matter, but I digress...)  W3C, on the other hand, is the authoritative source on HTML standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hsrc` attribute is not a valid HTML attribute, but it is a custom attribute, used by [this script](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/57528-rollover-image.html)

Comment: I found the same information. Custom JS Attribute for rollover.js

Answer (score 1):

custom attribute, the same as "master". if you put it into an html document and test it at w3c validator you get; "Attribute hsrc not allowed on element img at this point." and "Attribute master not allowed on element img at this point."

Answer (score 1):

[Doesn't look like a valid attribute to me](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2).

Chances are it's being used by some custom code on the page where you found it.  (Or was intended to be used as such and is just hanging around as a potential bug.)  I admit that I've done similar things in the past in web applications, such as adding an `iref` attribute as an alternate `href` used by custom JavaScript code.